# How to Insert values in Dictionary in swift

Tags: swift

I first declare dictionary

```
let storeSentenceOrdering = [String, Int ]();
```

then I want to insert value in it but I am getting an error:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to google the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add values in swift dictionary dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25397860/how-to-add-values-in-swift-dictionary-dynamically)

Comment: It's just wrong declaration. Change to: let storeSentenceOrdering = [String: Int]()

Comment: replace let with var and good luck

Answer (score 4):

**-** We can do this in following way

```
var carDictionary: [String:Int] = [:]

// Below is a subscript way of adding or updating value to the Dictionary, if the key is not present then the key is inserted with the assigned value else its updated with the new value

carDictionary["Ford"] = 345000
carDictionary["Hyundai"] = 546788

print(carDictionary)
```

**-** We can also use `update` to add value to the existing `Dictionary`

```
carDictionary.updateValue(234500,forKey:("Wolkswagen"))
```

**-** `Dictionary` can be initialized in one the following ways

```
var carDictionaryOne: [String:Int] = [:]
var carDictionaryTwo: [String:Int] = ()
var carDictionaryThree = ["Ford":12345, "Audi":57689]
```

Comment: @Uzair U are welcome dear.... but here in stackoverflow.com, thanks is usually conveyed by giving upvotes....

Answer (score 0):

try it...

```
      var dict : NSDictionary!
      dict = [1:"Hello", 2:"How", 3:"Are", 4:"You"]

      let value = dict[1] 
      print(value!)  // Print First Element

     //print all element

    for(var i=1; i<5; i++)
    {
        let value = dict[i]
        print(value)
    }
```